# How would I go about putting the multiple max and min values of an excel sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an excel sheet that graphs my data using pandas, matplot, and numpy but I also want it to give me both the max and min values of all the cycles I have. Here's an idea of how my data looks like except its about 50k rows and only reaches 21 cycles.

| Cycle | Voltage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.30 |
| 1 | 0.05 |
| 1 | -0.25 |
| 2 | 0.35 |
| 2 | 0.07 |
| 2 | -0.23 |

My best idea was to use a for loop to find the max and min in every cycle but can't seem to get it working at all and not really sure how to go about it.

Comment: Look up pandas's `groupby`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. For testing purposes, I put the following data in a CSV file:

```
Cycle,Voltage
1,0.30
1,0.05
1,-0.25
13,0.03
13,0.005
13,-0.025
2,0.35
2,0.07
2,-0.23
```

Here's the code:

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import NamedTuple


class Record(NamedTuple):
    """ Define the fields and their types of a record. """
    Cycle: int
    Voltage: float

    @classmethod
    def transform(cls: 'Record', dict_: dict) -> tuple:
        """ Convert string values in given dictionary to corresponding Record
            class field type."""
        return tuple(cls.__annotations__[name](value) for name, value in dict_.items())


filepath = 'voltages.csv'

with open(filepath, newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    data = sorted(map(Record.transform, reader))

groups = {}
for k, g in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)):
    voltages = tuple(map(itemgetter(1), g))
    groups[k] = (min(voltages), max(voltages))

print(groups)  # -> {1: (-0.25, 0.3), 2: (-0.23, 0.35), 13: (-0.025, 0.03)}
```